# Issues with AES Decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am having issues trying to decrypt some data from a file, I am using the following settings for `RijndaelManaged`. And this should be correct.

```
RijndaelManaged aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged
{
    KeySize = 128,
    Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
    Padding = PaddingMode.None,
    Key = new byte[] { 0x32, 0x1F, 0x2A, 0xEE, 0xAA, 0x58, 0x4A, 0xB4, 0x9A, 0x6C, 0x9E, 0x09, 0xD5, 0x9E, 0x9C, 0x6F }
};
```

However, whenever I use these settings the first 16 bytes are incorrect while the rest is correct. However is I switch to `Mode = CipherMode.ECB` the first 16 bytes are correct while the rest is incorrect. I know CBC uses information from the previous block to help encrypt/decrypt while ECB doesn't do this. Is there something extra that I am missing?

Here is some more information about what I am trying to do. The file I am reading from is about 25 Gigabytes and is actually a package of several files. I do have a script for a program called quickbms that is able to extract the files and I am trying to convert this into my own program. The script only provides a key and foregoes the IV. The individual chunks are encrypted separately, and I have modified the script to just output the chunks and comparing my results to this. In the mean time I have gotten it working by extracting the first 16 bytes and decrypting it with ECB, then decrypting the whole chunk of data with CBC and overwriting the first 16 bytes of the results with CBC with what I got from ECB. This produces the same result.

Comment: How was the file encrypted? How sure are you that the file is actually correct at all? How big is the file?

Comment: If you use CBC mode, where is the IV? Is it prepended to the ciphertext or do you need to supply it from outside?

Comment: I updated the post with more information to explain what I am trying to do and the information I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding before the };

```
    , IV = new byte[16]
};
```

If you don't initialize the IV, it is randomly generated, but perhaps they simply used an empty IV.

Note that I really hope they didn't use `Padding = PaddingMode.None,`, because it isn't reversible, but that is something you'll discover on the last block of data.

Comment: I forgot to update this, but I tried doing this and it worked perfectly. As for the padding, I have no idea but this is what works for me since the chunks are 0x150(336) bytes.

Comment: @7H3LaughingMan If the chunks are 336 bytes, then `Padding.None` is ok, because AES always uses 16 bytes blocks, and 336 is divisible by 16 (=21)

Answer (score 0):

You said CBC should be correct.  If it is encrypted in CBC then the IV should be provided WITH the encrypted data.

To encrypt in CBC mode you **generate a random IV** pass it, the key, and the first block of data into the AES algorithm to get the ciphertext.  For all subsequent blocks the IV is the prior block's ciphertext.

[image: CBC Encryption Block Diagram]

**To decrypt you need the same IV.**  If you are missing the IV all subsequent blocks are still decryptable because they are initialized not by the IV but by the prior block ciphertext.

[image: CBC Decryption Block Diagram]